# Request for reference for longitudinal data analysis which is mathematically well-written

Tags: references, panel-data, mathematical-statistics

I'm a person with graduate level mathematics and some undergraduate statistics background, who'll have to study some basic longitudinal data analysis. I've studied the basics of correlation and regression, measure-theoretic probability, all the necessary distributions (chi², T, F) for the previous, basic tests of confidence intervals etc.

I'm looking for textbooks/lecture notes which are mathematically well-written. By 'well-written', I mean it states the all the necessary results in a mathematically neat way, with or without necessarily going into details of the proof, or by referencing them wherever necessary.

I'm going to use these basic knowledge and results for statistical shape analysis/shape modelling, so may be an inclination to that subject would be preferred, but not absolutely necessary.

Comment: Many of us with pure mathematical backgrounds have found it enlightening to read non-mathematical accounts of methods of data analysis, once we figured out that *data analysis is not mathematics.* By focusing on the mathematical underpinnings of a particular statistical procedure you might overlook important information about how it is used, tested, extended, and interpreted within a particular context. I suspect any rigorous measure-theoretic account of longitudinal data analysis--if it even existed--would be unhelpful for actually learning how to do it.

Comment: And here's one example from ecol modelling: Dray et al. 2006 discussing the MEM framework http://biol09.biol.umontreal.ca/numecol/Reprints/Dray_et_al_Ecol_Modelling_2006.pdf

Comment: Thanks Katya for the link. Whuber: in that case, could you please suggest me some good textbooks/lecture notes which covers the subject well? It doesn't have to use measure theory, but should be nicely written.

Comment: [Fitzmaurice, Laird, and Ware](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Applied+Longitudinal+Analysis%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9780470380277) is written by accomplished practitioners and teachers (I have taken a short course by the first author, who did an excellent job at describing the characteristics and advantages of various longitudinal analysis procedures) and therefore should be worth a look.